# How to get specific value in Laravel query builder

Tags: php, laravel

I have 20 data in my table, but I just want to show 10 data in my view. How to get just 10 data from 20 data ?

My controller, something like this

```
public function getData(){
    $data['row'] = DB::table('my_table')->get();

    return view('home',$data);
}
```

My view, something like this

```
@foreach($row as $rows)
    <p>{{$rows->teks_data}}</p>
@end foreach
```

The point is how to show data from table with specific value ?

Comment: You can use limit https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Comment: `DB::table('my_table')->limit(10)->get();`

Comment: @Jaydp, its compatible with laravel 5.4 ?

Comment: @JustL - same thing available with Laravel 5.4 https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset    `DB::table('my_table')->limit(10)->get();`

Comment: thanks @Jaydp and sougata

Comment: you should answered it so i can accepted as a right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To limit data use take(10) or limit(10) like this

```
public function getData(){
    $data = DB::table('my_table')->limit(10)->get();

    return view('home',['data' => $data]);  // and send it like this
}
```

and retrive in view like this

```
@if(!empty($data))
    @foreach($data as $rows)
        <p>{{$rows->field_name_same_as_table}}</p>
    @endforeach  
@else
    <h3>Sorry! No data </h3>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `limit()` or `Paginate()`

```
$data['row'] = DB::table('my_table')->limit(10)->get(); // Query Builder approach

$data['row'] = MyTable::limit(10)->get(); // Eloquent approach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do using Laravel Eloquent model something like

```
public function getData(){
   $data = Model::take(10)->get();

   return view('home', compact('data'));  // and send it like this
}
```

and your view like this

```
@if(!empty($data))
  @foreach($data as $rows)
     <p>{{$rows->field_name_same_as_table}}</p>
  @endforeach  
  @else
    <h3>Sorry! No data </h3>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
public function getData(){
    $data['row'] = DB::table('my_table')->get();

    return view('home',compact($data));
}
```

In your view

```
@foreach($data['row'] as $rows)
    <p>{{$rows->teks_data}}</p>
@endforeach
```